# ¿Como puedo enviar varias imagenes a un servidor flask?

Tags: python, post, flask, requests

Necesito enviar este diccionario con el método requests.post con el parámetro file, a un servidor flask este diccionario contiene los nombres de las imágenes que quiero guardar y luego mostrar

```
dd = {
'img' : ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg','e.jpg']
}
```

Este es mi script de cliente que enviá las imágenes

```
import requests as RQ

dd = {
    'img' : ['a.jpg','b.jpg','c.jpg','d.jpg','e.jpg']
}

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:/8070/img_d'

#convierto el diccionario en una tupla   
mul_img = []
for v, k in enumerate(dd):
    a = dd.get(k)
    for i in a:
        mul_img.append((k, open(i, 'rb')))

Res = RQ.post(url, files=mul_img)

Res.text
```

y este es el servidor flask que si funciona

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
#from app import Res



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']= "./img"


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
    



#@app.route('/img_d', methods=['POST'])
#def i():
 #   return jsonify(Res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8070)
```

El problema que tengo es que cuando des comento las lineas me aparece un error

```
from app import Res  
@app.route('/img_d', methods=['POST'])
def i():
    return jsonify(Res)
```

El error cuando ejecuto el script de flask

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /8070/img_d (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x000001AB457DC6A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
> 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino
> denegó expresamente dicha conexión'))

en realidad no se lo que esta pasando y me gustaría si es que no fuese una molestia que me explicaran que es lo que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Parece problemas de CORS, has revisado eso??

Comment: @AlfaRojo no sabría como revisarlo en realidad, si tuvieses tiempo de explicarme un poco seria genial

Comment: pero parece que es un error con mi conversión del diccionario a tupla, ya que coloque el `dd` en vez del `mul_img` en la función RQ.post() y me sale un error diferente

Comment: Yo lo decia por `... ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión` y los problemas de CORS suelen estar por esos lados, negando conexiones, eso lo tenes que revisar junto a los headers que envias y el backend que lo recibe